# Issues with Godaddy - AWS WordPress website

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services

My domain is in Godaddy, I installed an instance and created required records in AWS. Name servers were updated by Cloudflare.  but the problem is when I check the website from Qatar I can see only a coming soon page by GoDaddy. but when the site checks from India, US it works fine. what will be the issue?

Comment: Looks like a DNS propagation issue? To ensure that it loads properly you validate that by updating your local `/etc/hosts`. Secondly use a site site like https://dnschecker.org/  to see how far the propagation has come...

Comment: Browse the site in incognito mode.

Comment: Tried in incognito, still the same